# Why it returns IndexError: list index out of range when index exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, index-error

[image: The question shows through the link]

Given a matrix constitutes of number 0 and 1, I am trying to find the maximum size of the square which only contains 1.

[image: My code]

I would get IndexError: list index out of range if I write the above code. However, if I change the code which is in line 34 into `if arr[i-1][j-1] == '1':`, then it works.

My question is how does this happen? I checked the type of item in arr, they are all int type, then why it doesn't work when I write `if arr[i-1][j-1] == 1:`?
Any answer will be helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: For questions seeking debugging help, *please provide a [mcve] in the question itself*. Post code as *formatted text*, not as links to code or even worse, pictures of code. Also, please always use the generic [python] tag for all python-related questions

Comment: Also, post the traceback. (Also, *read* the traceback!)

Comment: If your matrix contains numbers, `if arr[i-1][j-1] == '1':` will always fail, because a number is not equal to a string. So you never go into the rest of the code that has the error.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I am new to stack overflow, sorry for the inconvenience I made. I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

`dp` only has 1 row containing `(rows+1) * (cols+1)` zeroes, not `rows+1` rows with `cols+1` zeroes. So whenever you accessed `dp[i]` with `i >= 1` you get an error.

It should be:

```
dp = [[0 for i in range(cols+1)] for j in range(rows+1)]
```

or more simply

```
dp = [[0] * (cols+1) for _ in range(rows+1)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to stack overflow, sorry for the inconvenience I made because of not posting code as formatted text.